# Scaling heat map using geom_tile and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am trying to create a heat map using ggplot. I am using the following code:

```
ggplot(ff, aes(x=Days, y=variable)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=value),colour="blue") +
  scale_fill_gradient(limits=c(-1,1),low="blue",high="red",na.value="white")
```

Here are my questions:

1. How do I manipulate the scale unit in geom_tile ( so that instead of creating the heat map every 0.2 it will use a step of every 0.1 or 0.05)
2. Is it possible to use a richer color schema that I used ( for example some predefined color schema like in the heatmap function
3. There are NA in my dataframe that I render as white. Is there a better way to deal with NA and make it transparent?

The data ff is as follows:

```
Days    variable            value
1   4   Short.Range.Days..2 -0.81747353

2   6   Short.Range.Days..2 -0.548692305

3   8   Short.Range.Days..2 -0.344287337

4   10  Short.Range.Days..2 -0.214313697

5   12  Short.Range.Days..2 -0.166991021

6   14  Short.Range.Days..2 -0.087645101

7   16  Short.Range.Days..2 0.003306877

8   18  Short.Range.Days..2 0.014363975

9   20  Short.Range.Days..2 0.022512668

10  22  Short.Range.Days..2 0.040381662

11  24  Short.Range.Days..2 0.062312058

12  26  Short.Range.Days..2 0.079032057

13  28  Short.Range.Days..2 0.062894323

14  30  Short.Range.Days..2 0.042261172

15  32  Short.Range.Days..2 0.032980453

16  34  Short.Range.Days..2 0.040095505

17  36  Short.Range.Days..2 0.039992051

18  38  Short.Range.Days..2 0.006244882

19  40  Short.Range.Days..2 -0.005749414

20  42  Short.Range.Days..2 -0.008062039

21  44  Short.Range.Days..2 -0.023538994

22  46  Short.Range.Days..2 0.000465245

23  48  Short.Range.Days..2 0.011341621

24  50  Short.Range.Days..2 0.031610377

25  52  Short.Range.Days..2 0.043711238

26  54  Short.Range.Days..2 0.052674899

27  56  Short.Range.Days..2 0.052963846

28  58  Short.Range.Days..2 0.042461133

29  60  Short.Range.Days..2 0.041458926

30  4   Short.Range.Days..4 NA

31  6   Short.Range.Days..4 -0.564954032

32  8   Short.Range.Days..4 -0.376387471

33  10  Short.Range.Days..4 -0.212740266

34  12  Short.Range.Days..4 -0.107961718

35  14  Short.Range.Days..4 -0.072863517

36  16  Short.Range.Days..4 -0.013560192

37  18  Short.Range.Days..4 -0.014244693

38  20  Short.Range.Days..4 0.003714455

39  22  Short.Range.Days..4 0.018009887

40  24  Short.Range.Days..4 0.038299314

41  26  Short.Range.Days..4 0.048826919

42  28  Short.Range.Days..4 0.042215816

43  30  Short.Range.Days..4 0.026936439

44  32  Short.Range.Days..4 0.015311212

45  34  Short.Range.Days..4 0.024097239

46  36  Short.Range.Days..4 -0.004329243

47  38  Short.Range.Days..4 -0.001842634

48  40  Short.Range.Days..4 0.000926598

49  42  Short.Range.Days..4 -0.011272775

50  44  Short.Range.Days..4 -0.009693908

51  46  Short.Range.Days..4 -0.001668079

52  48  Short.Range.Days..4 0.016156964

53  50  Short.Range.Days..4 0.042374732

54  52  Short.Range.Days..4 0.046776012

55  54  Short.Range.Days..4 0.045923267

56  56  Short.Range.Days..4 0.050384377

57  58  Short.Range.Days..4 0.045215707

58  60  Short.Range.Days..4 0.047902343
59  4   Short.Range.Days..6 NA

60  6   Short.Range.Days..6 NA

61  8   Short.Range.Days..6 -0.441329726

62  10  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.238801239

63  12  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.15476164

64  14  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.059414124

65  16  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.061674965

66  18  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.025409294

67  20  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.009152774

68  22  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.001703372

69  24  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.000247112

70  26  Short.Range.Days..6 0.0253183

71  28  Short.Range.Days..6 0.039929109

72  30  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.001386462

73  32  Short.Range.Days..6 0.008182091

74  34  Short.Range.Days..6 0.029240807

75  36  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.002854685

76  38  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.007379733

77  40  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.004630816

78  42  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.011870576

79  44  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.015306308

80  46  Short.Range.Days..6 -0.005366024

81  48  Short.Range.Days..6 0.006607034

82  50  Short.Range.Days..6 0.018644749

83  52  Short.Range.Days..6 0.026165148

84  54  Short.Range.Days..6 0.036606456

85  56  Short.Range.Days..6 0.048953922

86  58  Short.Range.Days..6 0.043359266

87  60  Short.Range.Days..6 0.038203532

88  4   Short.Range.Days..8 NA

89  6   Short.Range.Days..8 NA

90  8   Short.Range.Days..8 NA

91  10  Short.Range.Days..8 -0.381950109

92  12  Short.Range.Days..8 -0.218592498

93  14  Short.Range.Days..8 -0.101448266

94  16  Short.Range.Days..8 -0.046656489

95  18  Short.Range.Days..8 -0.042095639

96  20  Short.Range.Days..8 -0.026922636

97  22  Short.Range.Days..8 -0.015991528

98  24  Short.Range.Days..8 -0.011757444

99  26  Short.Range.Days..8 0.007997248

100 28  Short.Range.Days..8 0.036514373


101 30  Short.Range.Days..8 0.006496822

102 32  Short.Range.Days..8 -0.004494976

103 34  Short.Range.Days..8 0.013963243

104 36  Short.Range.Days..8 0.022236117

105 38  Short.Range.Days..8 0.040222229

106 40  Short.Range.Days..8 0.024015061

107 42  Short.Range.Days..8 0.014655371

108 44  Short.Range.Days..8 -0.003435171

109 46  Short.Range.Days..8 0.004921792

110 48  Short.Range.Days..8 0.025002607

111 50  Short.Range.Days..8 0.039823008

112 52  Short.Range.Days..8 0.028497197

113 54  Short.Range.Days..8 0.033465104

114 56  Short.Range.Days..8 0.037187076

115 58  Short.Range.Days..8 0.035133715

116 60  Short.Range.Days..8 0.044956739

117 4   Short.Range.Days..10    NA

118 6   Short.Range.Days..10    NA

119 8   Short.Range.Days..10    NA

120 10  Short.Range.Days..10    NA

121 12  Short.Range.Days..10    -0.315010077

122 14  Short.Range.Days..10    -0.159081521

123 16  Short.Range.Days..10    -0.071303675

124 18  Short.Range.Days..10    -0.084264406

125 20  Short.Range.Days..10    -0.055602557

126 22  Short.Range.Days..10    -0.015130798

127 24  Short.Range.Days..10    0.005610983

128 26  Short.Range.Days..10    0.009360452

129 28  Short.Range.Days..10    0.00674219

130 30  Short.Range.Days..10    0.002157462

131 32  Short.Range.Days..10    0.00349763

132 34  Short.Range.Days..10    -0.001412894

133 36  Short.Range.Days..10    0.003717493

134 38  Short.Range.Days..10    0.002120068

135 40  Short.Range.Days..10    0.006367466

136 42  Short.Range.Days..10    -0.000411258

137 44  Short.Range.Days..10    0.012566411

138 46  Short.Range.Days..10    0.014464965

139 48  Short.Range.Days..10    0.031026233

140 50  Short.Range.Days..10    0.04388952

141 52  Short.Range.Days..10    0.042532374

142 54  Short.Range.Days..10    0.06035085

143 56  Short.Range.Days..10    0.054378445

144 58  Short.Range.Days..10    0.05048477

145 60  Short.Range.Days..10    0.064256151

146 4   Short.Range.Days..12    NA

147 6   Short.Range.Days..12    NA

148 8   Short.Range.Days..12    NA

149 10  Short.Range.Days..12    NA

150 12  Short.Range.Days..12    NA

151 14  Short.Range.Days..12    -0.227372691

152 16  Short.Range.Days..12    -0.156908358

153 18  Short.Range.Days..12    -0.097853165

154 20  Short.Range.Days..12    -0.031213742

155 22  Short.Range.Days..12    -0.002203366

156 24  Short.Range.Days..12    0.027172361

157 26  Short.Range.Days..12    -0.002829266

158 28  Short.Range.Days..12    0.003026913

159 30  Short.Range.Days..12    0.005941515

160 32  Short.Range.Days..12    0.005652349

161 34  Short.Range.Days..12    0.005849875

162 36  Short.Range.Days..12    0.008607215

163 38  Short.Range.Days..12    -0.008046473

164 40  Short.Range.Days..12    -0.003125555

165 42  Short.Range.Days..12    0.018868117

166 44  Short.Range.Days..12    0.017476927

167 46  Short.Range.Days..12    0.011919605

168 48  Short.Range.Days..12    0.021178085

169 50  Short.Range.Days..12    0.041199466

170 52  Short.Range.Days..12    0.034283292

171 54  Short.Range.Days..12    0.029778266

172 56  Short.Range.Days..12    0.039525157

173 58  Short.Range.Days..12    0.046134386

174 60  Short.Range.Days..12    0.065925521

175 4   Short.Range.Days..14    NA

176 6   Short.Range.Days..14    NA

177 8   Short.Range.Days..14    NA

178 10  Short.Range.Days..14    NA

179 12  Short.Range.Days..14    NA

180 14  Short.Range.Days..14    NA
181 16  Short.Range.Days..14    -0.261691083

182 18  Short.Range.Days..14    -0.142068675

183 20  Short.Range.Days..14    -0.074500031

184 22  Short.Range.Days..14    -0.012082714

185 24  Short.Range.Days..14    0.005659554

186 26  Short.Range.Days..14    0.012468794

187 28  Short.Range.Days..14    -0.002796818

188 30  Short.Range.Days..14    -0.007217387

189 32  Short.Range.Days..14    -0.011216542

190 34  Short.Range.Days..14    -0.012975914

191 36  Short.Range.Days..14    0.001431991

192 38  Short.Range.Days..14    -0.016442151

193 40  Short.Range.Days..14    -0.028879887

194 42  Short.Range.Days..14    -0.008744675

195 44  Short.Range.Days..14    0.003396965

196 46  Short.Range.Days..14    0.006496634

197 48  Short.Range.Days..14    0.034291641

198 50  Short.Range.Days..14    0.037316392

199 52  Short.Range.Days..14    0.025819292

200 54  Short.Range.Days..14    0.017700215

201 56  Short.Range.Days..14    0.030761449

202 58  Short.Range.Days..14    0.042412907

203 60  Short.Range.Days..14    0.064320329

204 4   Short.Range.Days..16    NA

205 6   Short.Range.Days..16    NA

206 8   Short.Range.Days..16    NA

207 10  Short.Range.Days..16    NA

208 12  Short.Range.Days..16    NA

209 14  Short.Range.Days..16    NA

210 16  Short.Range.Days..16    NA

211 18  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.24576188

212 20  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.124836183

213 22  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.048221263

214 24  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.035029068

215 26  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.017987078

216 28  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.008633172

217 30  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.031737817

218 32  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.0329801

219 34  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.022857234

220 36  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.033276605

221 38  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.041135562

222 40  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.040310448

223 42  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.039212637

224 44  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.022545529

225 46  Short.Range.Days..16    -0.003491653

226 48  Short.Range.Days..16    0.019354126

227 50  Short.Range.Days..16    0.01404553

228 52  Short.Range.Days..16    0.009496747

229 54  Short.Range.Days..16    0.021609426

230 56  Short.Range.Days..16    0.053664294

231 58  Short.Range.Days..16    0.034393419

232 60  Short.Range.Days..16    0.051344379

233 4   Short.Range.Days..18    NA

234 6   Short.Range.Days..18    NA

235 8   Short.Range.Days..18    NA

236 10  Short.Range.Days..18    NA

237 12  Short.Range.Days..18    NA

238 14  Short.Range.Days..18    NA

239 16  Short.Range.Days..18    NA

240 18  Short.Range.Days..18    NA

241 20  Short.Range.Days..18    -0.201415281

242 22  Short.Range.Days..18    -0.094650643

243 24  Short.Range.Days..18    -0.050407965

244 26  Short.Range.Days..18    -0.011944599

245 28  Short.Range.Days..18    0.006048385

246 30  Short.Range.Days..18    -0.009465899

247 32  Short.Range.Days..18    -0.010465794

248 34  Short.Range.Days..18    -0.017793544

249 36  Short.Range.Days..18    -0.043409233

250 38  Short.Range.Days..18    -0.047284525

251 40  Short.Range.Days..18    -0.034924265

252 42  Short.Range.Days..18    -0.035220327

253 44  Short.Range.Days..18    -0.038604807

254 46  Short.Range.Days..18    -0.017079637

255 48  Short.Range.Days..18    0.016028302

256 50  Short.Range.Days..18    0.012447745

257 52  Short.Range.Days..18    0.030016509

258 54  Short.Range.Days..18    0.047367639

259 56  Short.Range.Days..18    0.050529707

260 58  Short.Range.Days..18    0.043451669

261 60  Short.Range.Days..18    0.057382559

262 4   Short.Range.Days..20    NA

263 6   Short.Range.Days..20    NA

264 8   Short.Range.Days..20    NA

265 10  Short.Range.Days..20    NA

266 12  Short.Range.Days..20    NA

267 14  Short.Range.Days..20    NA

268 16  Short.Range.Days..20    NA

269 18  Short.Range.Days..20    NA

270 20  Short.Range.Days..20    NA

271 22  Short.Range.Days..20    -0.150659349

272 24  Short.Range.Days..20    -0.087423089

273 26  Short.Range.Days..20    -0.038100588

274 28  Short.Range.Days..20    -0.046059396

275 30  Short.Range.Days..20    -0.049492703

276 32  Short.Range.Days..20    -0.025327689

277 34  Short.Range.Days..20    -0.027303766

278 36  Short.Range.Days..20    -0.029267308

279 38  Short.Range.Days..20    -0.030914711

280 40  Short.Range.Days..20    -0.020236697

281 42  Short.Range.Days..20    -0.020736933

282 44  Short.Range.Days..20    -0.021439136

283 46  Short.Range.Days..20    -0.010624047

284 48  Short.Range.Days..20    0.016708851

285 50  Short.Range.Days..20    0.031313822

286 52  Short.Range.Days..20    0.041814604

287 54  Short.Range.Days..20    0.041267541

288 56  Short.Range.Days..20    0.057323017

289 58  Short.Range.Days..20    0.041221109

290 60  Short.Range.Days..20    0.05872252

291 4   Short.Range.Days..22    NA

292 6   Short.Range.Days..22    NA

293 8   Short.Range.Days..22    NA

294 10  Short.Range.Days..22    NA

295 12  Short.Range.Days..22    NA

296 14  Short.Range.Days..22    NA

297 16  Short.Range.Days..22    NA

298 18  Short.Range.Days..22    NA

299 20  Short.Range.Days..22    NA

300 22  Short.Range.Days..22    NA

301 24  Short.Range.Days..22    -0.15090012

302 26  Short.Range.Days..22    -0.104523303

303 28  Short.Range.Days..22    -0.092845968

304 30  Short.Range.Days..22    -0.083648125

305 32  Short.Range.Days..22    -0.046778288

306 34  Short.Range.Days..22    -0.058309377

307 36  Short.Range.Days..22    -0.045664863

308 38  Short.Range.Days..22    -0.015971201

309 40  Short.Range.Days..22    -0.0296146

310 42  Short.Range.Days..22    -0.013281189

311 44  Short.Range.Days..22    -0.014848272

312 46  Short.Range.Days..22    -0.011940442

313 48  Short.Range.Days..22    0.021530103

314 50  Short.Range.Days..22    0.031175715

315 52  Short.Range.Days..22    0.024433409

316 54  Short.Range.Days..22    0.033544534

317 56  Short.Range.Days..22    0.022443897

318 58  Short.Range.Days..22    0.025883639

319 60  Short.Range.Days..22    0.038383722

320 4   Short.Range.Days..24    NA

321 6   Short.Range.Days..24    NA

322 8   Short.Range.Days..24    NA

323 10  Short.Range.Days..24    NA

324 12  Short.Range.Days..24    NA

325 14  Short.Range.Days..24    NA

326 16  Short.Range.Days..24    NA

327 18  Short.Range.Days..24    NA

328 20  Short.Range.Days..24    NA

329 22  Short.Range.Days..24    NA

330 24  Short.Range.Days..24    NA

331 26  Short.Range.Days..24    -0.219027869

332 28  Short.Range.Days..24    -0.161214748

333 30  Short.Range.Days..24    -0.13408164

334 32  Short.Range.Days..24    -0.08070956

335 34  Short.Range.Days..24    -0.082899097

336 36  Short.Range.Days..24    -0.062595752

337 38  Short.Range.Days..24    -0.024198995

338 40  Short.Range.Days..24    -0.004691925

339 42  Short.Range.Days..24    -0.014496501

340 44  Short.Range.Days..24    -0.022884719

341 46  Short.Range.Days..24    -0.014154586

342 48  Short.Range.Days..24    0.000281776

343 50  Short.Range.Days..24    0.0071921

344 52  Short.Range.Days..24    -0.001297935

345 54  Short.Range.Days..24    -0.0015083

346 56  Short.Range.Days..24    -0.004905885

347 58  Short.Range.Days..24    0.001062168

348 60  Short.Range.Days..24    0.016119001

349 4   Short.Range.Days..26    NA

350 6   Short.Range.Days..26    NA

351 8   Short.Range.Days..26    NA

352 10  Short.Range.Days..26    NA

353 12  Short.Range.Days..26    NA

354 14  Short.Range.Days..26    NA

355 16  Short.Range.Days..26    NA

356 18  Short.Range.Days..26    NA

357 20  Short.Range.Days..26    NA

358 22  Short.Range.Days..26    NA

359 24  Short.Range.Days..26    NA

360 26  Short.Range.Days..26    NA

361 28  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.243817468

362 30  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.175056647

363 32  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.118290191

364 34  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.077769693

365 36  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.026417708

366 38  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.016489546

367 40  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.012463804

368 42  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.008863066

369 44  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.017249374

370 46  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.016538643

371 48  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.004546857

372 50  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.003654304

373 52  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.002765445

374 54  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.003328998

375 56  Short.Range.Days..26    -0.00821013

376 58  Short.Range.Days..26    0.002902259

377 60  Short.Range.Days..26    0.005409932
378 4   Short.Range.Days..28    NA

379 6   Short.Range.Days..28    NA

380 8   Short.Range.Days..28    NA

381 10  Short.Range.Days..28    NA

382 12  Short.Range.Days..28    NA

383 14  Short.Range.Days..28    NA

384 16  Short.Range.Days..28    NA

385 18  Short.Range.Days..28    NA

386 20  Short.Range.Days..28    NA

387 22  Short.Range.Days..28    NA

388 24  Short.Range.Days..28    NA

389 26  Short.Range.Days..28    NA

390 28  Short.Range.Days..28    NA

391 30  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.2017481

392 32  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.134879691

393 34  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.062318376

394 36  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.034419214

395 38  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.017322394

396 40  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.029575546

397 42  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.023687556

398 44  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.012397918

399 46  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.009062897

400 48  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.011838491

401 50  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.012319173

402 52  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.00739976

403 54  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.009963764

404 56  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.013427471

405 58  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.016496869

406 60  Short.Range.Days..28    -0.007558199

407 4   Short.Range.Days..30    NA

408 6   Short.Range.Days..30    NA

409 8   Short.Range.Days..30    NA

410 10  Short.Range.Days..30    NA

411 12  Short.Range.Days..30    NA

412 14  Short.Range.Days..30    NA

413 16  Short.Range.Days..30    NA

414 18  Short.Range.Days..30    NA

415 20  Short.Range.Days..30    NA

416 22  Short.Range.Days..30    NA

417 24  Short.Range.Days..30    NA

418 26  Short.Range.Days..30    NA

419 28  Short.Range.Days..30    NA

420 30  Short.Range.Days..30    NA

421 32  Short.Range.Days..30    -0.181026029

422 34  Short.Range.Days..30    -0.089303464

423 36  Short.Range.Days..30    -0.04590373

424 38  Short.Range.Days..30    -0.048539444

425 40  Short.Range.Days..30    -0.053611014

426 42  Short.Range.Days..30    -0.029848611

427 44  Short.Range.Days..30    -0.038913148

428 46  Short.Range.Days..30    -0.035174622

429 48  Short.Range.Days..30    -0.025815231

430 50  Short.Range.Days..30    -0.025238126

431 52  Short.Range.Days..30    -0.019484408

432 54  Short.Range.Days..30    -0.026327212

433 56  Short.Range.Days..30    -0.027493418

434 58  Short.Range.Days..30    -0.036467761

435 60  Short.Range.Days..30    0.003688413
```

Comment: You should probably try reducing your data to a smaller subset that demonstrates the problem more succintly, or hosting it as a text/csv file somewhere else and just linking to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. The size of the tiles is based on the smallest distance between the data point. You want smaller tiles? Then provide data with a fine resolution.
2. Have a look at scale_gradientn, scale_brewer or scale_hue
3. Missing values are transparent by default (http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_tile.html)